# jQuery and CSS, Issue using DIV

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

I've got a box with 2 tables, right and left.

Left is fine, but the right side contains a table that I need hidden on page load until a user enters a password, at which time that DIV will be toggled.

Using the most basic usage of jquery, I have this as the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#pwd').on('keyup', function() {

$('#right').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'access');
});
</script>

Inline CSS:
<style type="text/css">
#right {display:none;}
</style>
```

From there I have a form with only 1 field for the password. When the password is entered, everything inside the DIV with ID "right" toggles to show.

My issue is that within that right table, the content overflow is hidden and the (custom jQuery) scrollbar breaks when I use the DIV with ID "right".

There was an class entry in the main CSS file using "right" but was no longer being used anywhere, so I commented it out.

I've tried every different config of the CSS attribute, but nothing un-breaks the scrollbar.

Worth mentioning is that there is another jQuery object inside the "right" DIV, and also the scrollbar is the jQuery cScroll plugin.

Comment: I don't know about the others, but even though you gave a good description, I have trouble imagining the problem well. Pehaps making a JS Fiddle would be good.

Comment: My issue with that is that the code works properly in fiddle, but when I incorporate it into my whole site with JS and CSS, it goes haywire.

Comment: hi, be aware that anyone with any sort of view-source capability on the browser / viewer they are using can read the hidden div, unless that content is ajaxed in on password entry. in addition, anyone with any knowledge of firebug or chrome's dev tools can just set that div to visible

Comment: That's not an issue, this is only for a copyright technicality and aesthetics.

Comment: @PCLove It's going to take a lot of time, but you could try to gradually add elements from your site to your fiddle and test at each step. At some point it should stop working and tell you where the error is. Probably.

Comment: perhaps the scrollbar plugin you are using would prefer it if you used `visibility: hidden;` rather than `display: none;` , as in the former case the hidden div still contributes to its container's height

Comment: I tried that just now and the toggle doesn't work with "visibility:none".

Comment: try with `opacity:0`, and use `fadeIn()`

Comment: The opacity tag doesn't toggle the div.

Comment: @PCLove, as you said in the above comments, "it works fine in js fiddle, but has problem when incorporated". Then there is no problem with your existing code, may be it is created problem with other .js and css styles, do one thing, just give uinque id for this particular table and use different css classes. Make a try and let me know the scnerio.

Comment: add overflow:auto; to the right div? I agree with Ariane, jfiddle would make this easy to understand.

Comment: @SAM, Here's my scenario:
Div1: box
Div2: pad
Div3: line1
Div4: column1 (table1)
Div5: column2 (table2)
Div5a: relative
Div5b: scroll
Div5c: right (the one I'm implementing)
[content]
[7 closing DIVs]

Could this be something as simple as CSS sizing for these elements, particularly the right column?

Comment: @Prospector, overflow:auto makes the scrollbar work.

Now, on page load, the DIV is shown until I type 1 keystroke, then it disappears until the correct phrase is entered, then it shows again.

Getting closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing and troubleshooting, the problem was isolated to the jQuery scrollbar that I had used when I first built the page. This scrollbar was based on the jQuery library 1.3.

Since adding that scrollbar, I've implemented a few other jQuery scripts, of which the highest used library was 1.7.

After updating my jQuery to 1.9 and adding jQuery migrate for the old plugins, the scrollbar was malfunctioning when used with the DIV "show/hide".

I changed jQuery scrollbars and the problem I originally posted about disappeared. The new scrollbar is the simple yet attractive [EnScroll](http://enscrollplugin.com).

@Prospector, thank you for all the help trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, since your last comment to me, this might be what you're missing

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#right').hide();
    $('#pwd').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#right').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'access');
    });
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">
#right {display:none;overflow:auto;}
</style>
```

Comment: I did exactly that and toggle works, but scrollbar is back to broken.

also tried many variations of the css and placement of the DIV.

Comment: I tried that previously but it adds a browser scrollbar, which defeats the purpose of using a custom jQuery scrollbar.

Comment: well I didn't know you had a custom jquery scrollbar. try overflow:hidden;position:relative     that's my last guess without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given consideration to just getting the value of the input?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#right').hide();
    $('#pwd').on('keyup', function() {
        if($('#pwd').val()=='access'){
         $('#right').show();
        }
        else{
         $('#right').hide();
        }        
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This achieves the same result of the broken scrollbar, although the toggle does work without any inline css.

Comment: try position:relative with overflow:auto;